# How to create formula field to get values as startdate+120 days

Tags: formula-field

I would like to display new formula field value for startdate+120 days, where as startdate is Data Type of Roll-Up Summary. And the value of start date look like as(Start Date 15/03/2015).

Comment: Create a formula field of date type and in formula editor paste the `field API name`  + 120. Save it

Comment: i had given Start_Date__c+120 and click on check syntax then i can see below error Error: Field Start_Date__c may not be used in this type of formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a formula field of `Date` type

1. In formula editor paste the code as

   ```
   Field_API_name__c + 120
   ```
2. Save it